# Backup-manager archive name when uploading to s3

Tags: amazon-s3, backup

I am using `backup-manager` to back up a directory's content say `/home`.
I want to upload the archive file to `s3` bucket.
I have a directory structure in s3 bucket say `/bucket_name/x/y/`
If I write `export BM_UPLOAD_S3_DESTINATION="bucket_name"`, the archive will be uploaded to `bucket_name/`
If I write in `export BM_UPLOAD_S3_DESTINATION="bucket_name/x/y/"`, then error occurs that bucket name should not be like IP addresses.
But I want the archive to be uploaded to `bucket_name/x/y/`.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `BM_ARCHIVE_PREFIX` doesn't help, we can ask backup-manager to generate the backup file but not to upload it. We can write a script to upload the file and can specify whatever address we want in the script. That's the only feasible solution.

Answer (score 1):

`BM_UPLOAD_S3_DESTINATION` should be the name of the bucket to upload to, as explained [here](https://github.com/sukria/Backup-Manager/blob/master/backup-manager.conf.tpl#L450).

Since technically, [there isn't such a thing as directories/folders on S3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/UG/FolderOperations.html), you could use `BM_ARCHIVE_PREFIX` setting it to `x/y/`.

This way your object will have a name like `x/y/backup.txt` and will end up inside the directories you have created.

Comment: just discovered it, thanks although, http://docshare01.docshare.tips/files/18511/185113334.pdf tells a lot about backup-manager and looks updated too.

Comment: Yes, I saw the guide but I couldn't link a specific place. By the way you could also use `BM_UPLOAD_DESTINATION`

Comment: BM_UPLOAD_DESTINATION is overriden by BM_UPLOAD_S3_DESTINATION (Page 23)

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. The file name is still backup.txt and not x/y/backup.txt although the file is saved at x/y/backup.txt

Comment: If the file is saved there then the key is necessary x/y/backup.txt, the file name itself doesn't matter. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html

Comment: I mean in the local file system the file is saved at x/y/ but when uploading to s3 bucket using backup manager, then the file name is only backup.txt and hence backup-manager tries to upload it to bucket_name/ rather than bucket_name/x/y/

Comment: Right, now I understand. Looking at the code the problem is here https://github.com/sukria/Backup-Manager/blob/master/backup-manager-upload#L924 calling basename http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Basename.html will return backup.txt. You could ask them to consider changing it, or change it yourself